# Disable constant folding for LLVM 10 C++ API

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, llvm, constantfolding

I'm using the LLVM C++ API to write a compiler front-end for a subset of the C language. I've noticed the generated IR always has the constant folding optimization applied. But I want to disable this and get a faithful, unoptimized IR. Is there any way to do this?

Following is the code I'm using to generate IR from my module.

```
    llvm::verifyModule(kit.module, &llvm::outs());
    kit.module.print(llvm::outs(), nullptr);
    auto tirFile = "output.ir";
    error_code ec;
    llvm::raw_fd_ostream tirFileStream(tirFile, ec, llvm::sys::fs::F_None);
    kit.module.print(tirFileStream, nullptr);
    tirFileStream.flush();
```

Seems like the version of LLVM I'm using is LLVM 10.

```
sumit@HAL9001:~$ llvm-config --version
10.0.0
```

For example, when I run my compiler on the following C function

```
int arith() {
  return (10 - 10/3) << 3 | (23+8*12) & 1024;
}
```

It gets compiled to

```
define i32 @arith() {
entry:
  ret i32 56
}
```

The binary operations on constants are evaluated by the compiler itself, i.e. constant folding; it doesn't get translated to appropriate IR code.

Comment: That code ought not change the IR. Printing just prints, AFAICT. But you can always set a breakpoint. Look at the functions in ConstantFolding.cpp, find one that you suspect is called, set a breakpoint, run your code and look at the stack when the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: This does not change the IR per se, but the generated IR has constant folding built in. I've edited to question and added an example.

Comment: You're using IRBuilder in your frontend? You can create Instructions yourself, it's simple. Most of the IRBuilder methods are four-argument wrappers around a four-argument methods called SomethingInst::Create(). Some are more complex, e.g. creating an addition is if(all args constant) { part you don't want } else { BinaryOperation::Create(…}; }

Comment: @arnt I see, so their IRBuilder implementation does the constant folding. So there's no straightforward way of disabling it, I thought it was more like an optimization pass that was automatically applied. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: There's no way without dropping IRBuilder. But dropping IRBuilder is not at all complicated.

Answer (score 2):

In LLVM 11 you can use
`IRBuilder<llvm::NoFolder>` instead of `IRBuilder<>`

I'm pretty sure it works for LLVM 10 too (although I haven't verified that).

Don't forget to `#include <llvm/IR/NoFolder.h>` :)

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [this link](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2019-January/129450.html):

> The way that the front-end lowers code to IR causes this sort of
> constant folding to happen even before any LLVM IR is generated.
> Essentially, when you do the AST traversal, you’re going to
> essentially see the following code get run:

```cpp
IRBuilder<> Builder; Value *LHS = Builder.getInt32(2); 
Value *RHS = Builder.getInt32(4); // LHS and RHS are ConstantInt values because they’re constant expressions.
Value *Res = Builder.CreateMul(LHS,RHS); // Because LHS and RHS are constant values, the IRBuilder folds this to a constant expression.
```

> This constant folding cannot be turned off. (I’m also assuming there’s
> no other constant folding going on at the Clang AST level).

Comment: I did see that mailing list thread, but I assumed that's just how Clang implements it, and at the API level there would be more flexibility.  But as @arnt pointed out in a comment to the question, it is indeed something built into the IRBuilder code. Thanks!