# How to generate LLVM IR without optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, llvm

I am writing an LLVM PASS to analyze info in registers. It seems that `IRBuilder` optimized my code automatically, making an expression to be an operand. For example, I write down below code to generate LLVM IR.

```
// %reg = getelementptr inbounds ([128 x i256], [128 x i256]* @mstk, i256 0, i256 0
std::vector<llvm::Value*> indices(2, llvm::ConstantInt::get(Type::Int256Ty, 0));
llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value *> indicesRef(indices);
llvm::Value* m_sp = m_builder.CreateGEP(conArray, indicesRef, "spPtr"); 

// store 0, *%m_sp
m_builder.CreateStore(llvm::ConstantInt::get(Type::Int256Ty, 0), m_sp);
```

The expected IR should consist of two registers. (see below)

```
%reg = getelementptr inbounds ([128 x i256], [128 x i256]* @mstk, i256 0, i256 0)
store i256 0, i256* reg
```

Unfortunately, IRBuilder optimizes the IR by combining the registers.

```
store i256 0, i256* getelementptr inbounds ([128 x i256], [128 x i256]* @mstk, i256 0, i256 0)
```

**Is it possible to disable the IR optimization?** I have made sure that I turned off all PASS. Thanks.

Comment: Please add the commands you're using for running your pass.

Comment: My project is a binary translater based on llvm-10, which converts a kind of binary code to Webassembly.  Maybe there are few useful info in my commands.  I dump the IR immediately after editing the llvm::module. Maybe there are some options in the llvm::IRBuilder? Thanks.

Comment: You can turn off all optimization passes by using `-Xclang -disable-llvm-passes` flag if you are running your pass with clang as `clang -S -emit-llvm -Xclang -load -Xclang yourpass.so -Xclang -disable-llvm-passes example.c -o example.ll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by disabling the constant folder of IR builder. See [Disable constant folding for LLVM 10 C++ API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65246019/disable-constant-folding-for-llvm-10-c-api)