# How do I really disable all rustc optimizations?

Tags: rust, llvm, riscv

I'm trying to learn assembly through compiling Rust. I have found a way to compile Rust code to binary machine code and be able to `objdump` it to view the assembly. However if I write the following:

```
#![no_main]

#[link_section = ".text.entry"]
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn _start() -> ! {
    let a: u64 = 4;
    let b: u64 = 7;
    let c: u64 = a * b;
    
    loop {}
}
```

The assembly I get is:

```
0000000000000000 <.data>:
   0:   1101                    addi    sp,sp,-32
   2:   4511                    li      a0,4
   4:   e42a                    sd      a0,8(sp)
   6:   451d                    li      a0,7
   8:   e82a                    sd      a0,16(sp)
   a:   4571                    li      a0,28
   c:   ec2a                    sd      a0,24(sp)
   e:   a009                    j       0x10
  10:   a001                    j       0x10
```

So it looks like rust is collapsing the mul to a constant. I'm using the following compile options:

Cargo.toml:

```
[profile.dev]
opt-level = 0
mir-opt-level = 0
```

Is there a way to stop Rust from optimizing this?

The LLVM emitted looks like this:

```
; Function Attrs: noreturn nounwind
define dso_local void @_start() unnamed_addr #0 section ".text.entry" !dbg !22 {
start:
  %c.dbg.spill = alloca i64, align 8
  %b.dbg.spill = alloca i64, align 8
  %a.dbg.spill = alloca i64, align 8
  store i64 4, i64* %a.dbg.spill, align 8, !dbg !36
  call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata i64* %a.dbg.spill, metadata !28, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !37
  store i64 7, i64* %b.dbg.spill, align 8, !dbg !38
  call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata i64* %b.dbg.spill, metadata !31, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !39
  store i64 28, i64* %c.dbg.spill, align 8, !dbg !40
  call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata i64* %c.dbg.spill, metadata !33, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !41
```

So it looks like the optimization is before the LLVM pass.

```sh
$ rustc --version                                                                                                                                           
rustc 1.60.0-nightly (c5c610aad 2022-02-14)
```

Command to build:

```sh
RUSTFLAGS="--emit=llvm-bc" cargo build --target riscv64imac-unknown-none-elf --no-default-features
```

build.rs

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=build.rs");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=-Tlink.ld");
}
```

link.ld

```
ENTRY(_start)
SECTIONS {
  .text : { *(.text); *(.text.*) }
}
```

Comment: If you are willing to change the code a bit and to go unsafe, you can use [volatile](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.read_volatile) access to avoid these kinds of optimizations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is one compiler pass before the generation of LLVM-IR, which is the generation of [MIR](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/mir/index.html), the Rust intermediate representation. If you emit this for the given code with a command such as this one:

```sh
cargo rustc -- --emit mir
```

You will see in the .mir file generated that the optimization already took place there.

```rust
fn _start() -> ! {
    let mut _0: !;                       // return place in scope 0 at src\main.rs:5:31: 5:32
    let _1: u64;                         // in scope 0 at src\main.rs:6:9: 6:10
    scope 1 {
        debug a => _1;                   // in scope 1 at src\main.rs:6:9: 6:10
        let _2: u64;                     // in scope 1 at src\main.rs:7:9: 7:10
        scope 2 {
            debug b => _2;               // in scope 2 at src\main.rs:7:9: 7:10
            let _3: u64;                 // in scope 2 at src\main.rs:8:9: 8:10
            scope 3 {
                debug c => _3;           // in scope 3 at src\main.rs:8:9: 8:10
            }
        }
    }

    bb0: {
        _1 = const 4_u64;                // scope 0 at src\main.rs:6:18: 6:19
        _2 = const 7_u64;                // scope 1 at src\main.rs:7:18: 7:19
        _3 = const 28_u64;               // scope 2 at src\main.rs:8:18: 8:23
        goto -> bb1;                     // scope 3 at src\main.rs:10:5: 10:12
    }

    bb1: {
        goto -> bb1;                     // scope 3 at src\main.rs:10:5: 10:12
    }
}
```

This is happening because the `mir-opt-level` option currently only exists as an *unstable compiler option*. It is *not* available as a profile property in Cargo. Set it manually on a direct call to the compiler:

```
cargo rustc -- -Z mir-opt-level=0 --emir mir
```

And this optimization will disappear:

```
fn _start() -> ! {
    let mut _0: !;                       // return place in scope 0 at src\main.rs:5:31: 5:32
    let mut _1: !;                       // in scope 0 at src\main.rs:5:33: 11:2
    let _2: u64;                         // in scope 0 at src\main.rs:6:9: 6:10
    let mut _5: u64;                     // in scope 0 at src\main.rs:8:18: 8:19
    let mut _6: u64;                     // in scope 0 at src\main.rs:8:22: 8:23
    let mut _7: (u64, bool);             // in scope 0 at src\main.rs:8:18: 8:23
    let mut _8: !;                       // in scope 0 at src\main.rs:10:5: 10:12
    let mut _9: ();                      // in scope 0 at src\main.rs:5:1: 11:2
    scope 1 {
        debug a => _2;                   // in scope 1 at src\main.rs:6:9: 6:10
        let _3: u64;                     // in scope 1 at src\main.rs:7:9: 7:10
        scope 2 {
            debug b => _3;               // in scope 2 at src\main.rs:7:9: 7:10
            let _4: u64;                 // in scope 2 at src\main.rs:8:9: 8:10
            scope 3 {
                debug c => _4;           // in scope 3 at src\main.rs:8:9: 8:10
            }
        }
    }

    bb0: {
        StorageLive(_1);                 // scope 0 at src\main.rs:5:33: 11:2
        StorageLive(_2);                 // scope 0 at src\main.rs:6:9: 6:10
        _2 = const 4_u64;                // scope 0 at src\main.rs:6:18: 6:19
        StorageLive(_3);                 // scope 1 at src\main.rs:7:9: 7:10
        _3 = const 7_u64;                // scope 1 at src\main.rs:7:18: 7:19
        StorageLive(_4);                 // scope 2 at src\main.rs:8:9: 8:10
        StorageLive(_5);                 // scope 2 at src\main.rs:8:18: 8:19
        _5 = _2;                         // scope 2 at src\main.rs:8:18: 8:19
        StorageLive(_6);                 // scope 2 at src\main.rs:8:22: 8:23
        _6 = _3;                         // scope 2 at src\main.rs:8:22: 8:23
        _7 = CheckedMul(_5, _6);         // scope 2 at src\main.rs:8:18: 8:23
        assert(!move (_7.1: bool), "attempt to compute `{} * {}`, which would overflow", move _5, move _6) -> bb1; // scope 2 at src\main.rs:8:18: 8:23
    }

    bb1: {
        _4 = move (_7.0: u64);           // scope 2 at src\main.rs:8:18: 8:23
        StorageDead(_6);                 // scope 2 at src\main.rs:8:22: 8:23
        StorageDead(_5);                 // scope 2 at src\main.rs:8:22: 8:23
        StorageLive(_8);                 // scope 3 at src\main.rs:10:5: 10:12
        goto -> bb2;                     // scope 3 at src\main.rs:10:5: 10:12
    }

    bb2: {
        _9 = const ();                   // scope 3 at src\main.rs:10:10: 10:12
        goto -> bb2;                     // scope 3 at src\main.rs:10:5: 10:12
    }
}
```

---

And this is probably as far as you can go without touching LLVM directly. Some optimisations in specific parts of the code can also be prevented through constructs such as [`black_box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/hint/fn.black_box.html).

See also:

- [Rustc dev guide book on MIR optimizations](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/mir/optimizations.html)

Comment: That's perfect, thanks so much! I haven't investigated much yet, but I noticed that if I change to: let c = a.wrapping_mul(b); it seems to optimize out the mul again :) I'll take a look at the MIR options

Comment: Even if the MIR doesn't, LLVM's constant folding is likely to do the same thing, unless you [modify the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67049373), which seems like a long detour for learning assembly.

Comment: I see, I guess I reached the limit of what we can expect the tools to not optimize since it's not quite designed for that. Thanks for the link!